# Makefile issues

Tags: c, makefile

i have an assignment in a C class where our teacher and the whole arrangement is so bad. We have not been taught anything about makefiles, and now we are supposed to compile and use an md5 implementation for the assignment, but we have never been taught how to do so. I have read much about makefiles but i still cant seem to make this one work.

I have the following files:

- md5.c
- md5.h
- md5_example.c
- md5_test.c
- print_md5.c

This is my makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS = -g -O0

1: md5_example.o
$(CC) -o md5_example $(CFLAGS) md5_example.o

2: md5.o
    $(CC) -o md5 $(CFLAGS) md5.o

3: md5_test.o
    $(CC) -o md5_test $(CFLAGS) md5_test.o

4: print_md5.o
    $(CC) -o print_md5 $(CFLAGS) print_md5.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o md5 md5_example md5_test print_md5
```

The error i am getting is:

```
md5_example.c:2:17: fatal error: md5.h: No such file or directory
```

Can someone please help me figured out how i can compile these files together?

Comment: Are md5.h and md5_example.c in the same directory? Is the makefile in this directory also? Are you running make there?

Comment: Please explain what your think `1:`, `2:` and so on mean in your Makefile. So far it seem like you do not understand the use of `X:Y` in makefiles.

Comment: You should give names for the targets which match the names of the files generated. That is, use `md5_example: md5_example.o` instead of `1: md5_example.o`, etc. And then you should at [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html); almost your entire Makefile can be handled automatically.

Comment: Also, your problem is likely related to your directory structure and the way you include the header files., not to your Makefile yet. Are all files (.c and .h) in the same directory?

Comment: The `1:` notation is unorthodox at best and wrong at worst.

Comment: You may need to use `-I.` on the command line if you've used `#include <md5.h>` instead of `#include "md5.h"`.

Comment: What **simpler thing** do you know how to do? Can you compile these files and build the executable on the command line, without Make? Have you tried writing a makefile for `HelloWorld`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm a little confused by your lines starting 1: etc, I would expect to see:

```
md5_example: md5_example.o
```

That aside, you are creating `md5_example.o` from `md5_example.c` via an implicit (built-in) rule which is fine. The problem is with the compilation; are you sure that `md5_example.c` contains:

```
#include "md5.h"
```

and not this?

```
#include <md5.h>
```

However it would be better to have an explicit entry for `md5_example.o` which includes `md5.h` as a dependency. You could simply write:

```
md5_example: md5_example.c md5.h
    $(CC) -o md5_example $(CFLAGS) md5_example.c
```

Comment: Note that you should indent 'code' by 4 spaces to get the result I showed.  Or select it in the edit box and use the **`{}`** button above the box to indent it.

Comment: In your last line command, it is likely that the program needs `md5.o` in the linking.  You also don't need to specify `md5_example.c` as an explicit dependency (though no harm is done by doing so) as `make` can infer the correct dependency.

Comment: I changed <md5.h> to "md5.h", but now i get; make
gcc -o md5 -g -O0 md5.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'

Answer (score -1):

The way to pass the test, and deserve to, is to learn where you are going wrong and how to fix it :-)

The error is pretty much what it says: your C file does not contain a main() function.

Your makefile looks like it has a number of possible targets, do you in fact wish to compile and link all the .C files together? A quick search for "gnu make tutorial" could pay dividends...

John